# Remove Border from MahApps FlipView

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

How to remove the `Border` that appears on mouseover the [MahApps.Metro FlipView](http://mahapps.com/controls/flipview.html) control.

```
<mahAppsControls:FlipView IsBannerEnabled="False">
    <mahAppsControls:FlipView.Items>
        ...
    </mahAppsControls:FlipView.Items>
</mahAppsControls:FlipView>
```

Left-hand side the normal state and right-hand side when mouse is over the control and a thick border appears that I need to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Source](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Themes/FlipView.xaml) shows that since the commit from **Jan 9, 2015** the behavior is controlled by the `MouseOverGlowEnabled` property.

Use `MouseOverGlowEnabled="False"` in your XAML to disable that like:

```
<UserControl 
...
xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">
    <Controls:FlipView x:Name="alertFlipView"
                       MouseOverGlowEnabled="False"
                       ... />
```

**Update:**
In new versions (since 1.3.0) the `MouseOverGlowEnabled` property was replaced with `MouseHoverBorderEnabled`, see [Release notes](https://mahapps.com//2016/09/23/v1.3.0.html)

Comment: How to set that in XAML? There's no direct property to do that.

Comment: At least for me there is... probably you have to update your lib version (pre-release?) the Property was introduced Jan 9, 2015

Comment: Ah, I have a version older than that.

Comment: In newer versions, MouseOverGlowEnabled has been replaced with MouseHoverBorderEnabled